Did any PC disk defragmentor optimize cylinder position?
Defragmentation was used to minimize harddisk waiting times as the read head - which took milliseconds to move - was close to the next file to read when done with this one.
In hard drives with multiple platters, each side of each disk had its own read head, and all of them could be doing I/O simultaneously.  Data was written cylinder-first bits written simultaneously in parallel), and then the track was written (one rotation), and only then would the head move.
I'm not familiar with any PC defragmenting software that paid attention to cylinders. Or maybe they all did, and they just never talked about it.

Drives only processed the signal from one read head at a time.  Duplicating the circuity for each head would be too expensive for drives used in a PC.

@Brian Nobody did it? It would quadruple the IO speed of a two platter disk. Other hand, they had to use interleaving because they couldn't handle the data already. So should this question be closed or what?

I don't know if any defragmenters implemented it for the reason you suggest, but I'm nearly 99.9% sure that some did for other reasons.  I could swear that Diskeeper, for example (could have been a different one though) would move directories to the outer tracks which had more sectors so that more of them would fit and there's be less head movement when traversing directories.  (Can anyone confirm or refute this?)

@MissUnderstands The problem is heads on the arm don't always stay in a straight vertical line, they drift laterally particularly with temperature. Thus, the actuator can only follow, and heads can only access one surface at a time. This head-to-head offset was the reason behind the thermal recalibration interruptions that were needed through the 90's, when they used dedicated servo surfaces.

"each side of each disk had its own read head, and all of them could be doing I/O simultaneously" - no, they could not. There was a single disk controller able to select one head at a time for an operation. Having multiple heads active simultaneously would have meant more expensive drives, and if this were done the disk controller could just have hidden the fact that there are multiple heads as it could have written the sector data directly using multiple heads.

Not only couldn't the IO system keep up with reading data from multiple heads, but on older PCs (like the original PC/XT) many hard drive controllers couldn't even keep up with one head. That's why disks in those really old computers got formatted with what's called an "interleave" value, so that after reading one sector, enough lag time was allowed that the next sector required hadn't already passed by the read head by the time the controller was ready to read more data (in a sequential read)

@mnem: I wonder how much it would have cost to have a hard drive controller with enough RAM to hold two tracks, and hardware that could, when asked to move the head to a track whose data hadn't yet been read, could move the head and then read sectors in whatever order they arrive, and once that was done advance to the next head or cylinder and read that track as well, so that if the PC wanted to read data sequentially at any rate up to the raw data rate of the drive it would never need to wait for the disk?

@supercat I'm honestly not sure if the bottleneck was the hard drive controller, the PC / CPU itself, or saturation of the ISA bus (which only ran at a CPU synchronous clock speed) on an XT. Whichever the case, I'd guess any gains to be had would be pretty minimal at least until the advent of faster "Turbo XT" systems.

@mnem: On the XT, there was no overlapping of data transfer and other processing.  On an XT system, if processing each sector would take between roughly 1.1x and 2x as long as reading it, data would need to be stored with a 3:1 interleave, meaning the drive would need to spin about three times to read a 17-sector track.  If the disk was written with 3:1 interleave and processing was a little slower than that, the disk would need to spin about 20 times to read a 17-sector track.  Adding buffering as described would mean that reading a track's worth of data into the buffer would take...

...just over one revolution (regardless of the interleave factor used to write it); if processing each sector took 1.5x as long as physically reading it, than the sustained data rate would be 1/1.5x the raw data rate rather than being 1/3x.  In scenarios that involved more processing which would take 2.5x as long as physically reading each sector the data rate would go from 1/20 the physical rate to 1/2.5x.  If one wanted to avoid massively slowing down tasks that would take 2x-3x as long to process each sector to read it one could use a 4:1 interleave, but that would reduce the best-case...

...transfer rate to 1/4 of the drive's raw data rate.  Having track buffering would allow a drive to efficiently handle many kinds of tasks.

Trixter's answer to your "did any" is "yes" if the program did consider cylinders. Consider it being the correct answer to your question.

That's a matter for file system geometry, not defragmenters.  Consider a disk as having blocks logically numbered 1 to N.  Arranging those blocks on the disk is done by (depending on system) either the file system or the disk driver.
Any sensible system will arrange that contiguous logical blocks will be readable with minimum head movement.  That is, it will take note of cylinders.
If the file system does not do this, then it would be counter-productive to have a defragmenter do it.  The reason is that contiguous blocks of a file would then NOT map to contiguous disk ('logical') blocks. The file is thus made up of many extents, each of which then requires separate metadata to describe it - which requires more disk space to store, and possible more disk I/O to retrieve in order to read a file.
In current disk hardware, the mapping of logical blocks to physical disk addresses occurs in the controller.

There was a single PC/DOS defragmentation software that paid attention to disk geometry:  FastTrax.  Its claim to fame was that it didn't merely defragment files, but also arranged them to cylinder/head/sector boundaries to fit as many files within cylinder boundaries as possible.  To denote this, the on-screen display made a point to differentiate between a file that were merely "contiguous" (no geometry concerns) or "optimized" (aligned to geometry boundaries).
It was maintained into the 1990s, and the last version (5.x) supported preserving long filenames if you were using it on a FAT-formatted drive that also held Windows 95.  It was also very flexible, allowing exact placement of files near the FAT, near specific subdirectories, and other features.

Were their any independent benchmarks?

Infoworld and PC Magazine reviewed defragmenters a lot, but mostly on their features, cost, and support; I'm not sure any had end-result performance tests.

"each side of each disk had its own read head, and all of them could be doing I/O simultaneously" - no, they could not.
There was a single disk controller able to select one head at a time for an operation.
Having multiple heads active simultaneously would have meant more expensive drives, and if this were done the disk controller could just have hidden the fact that there are multiple heads as it could have written the sector data directly using multiple heads.
Also on many occasions the disk has some physical geometry, but it is traslated to some other logical geometry for some reason (e.g. to pass BIOS limits in PC to access drives larger than 504MB, or to simulate 2048 byte sectors so you have less sectors that are larger in OS), and OS such as DOS does not use physical or logical geometry but linear sector numbers inside a file system.
Sometimes a hard disk may not have a fixed number of physical sectors on each physical cylinder, drives may have internally more sectors on outer tracks than inner tracks.
For these reasons, it is impossible to reliably defrag files and map them to start on a physical cylinder boundary.

Even disks with heads on independently-movable arms (like KDF9's disk) could only be transferring from one head. The rest of the heads could be seeking.

See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/643792/why-do-hard-disks-use-only-one-head-at-a-time for why it can't be done these days.  Although I suppose with heads with separate fine alignment it might be possible in the future.


Did any PC disk defragmentor optimize cylinder position?

No, but...

In prehistoric times, defragging utilities used to have feature battles, because there was a big market.

Let's better agree that anything PC is rather modern times. Also, while defragmenting wasn't a bad idea, it was usually only notable for heavily fragmented files that in addition were spread out and possibly reverse allocated. And even then it only mattered if that file was really used a lot and with continuous reading. Otherwise any effect was rather neglectable in real world scenarios.
For most of the time defragmenters were snake oil with no real benefit, but giving a great feel of having done something helpful to improve ... also a nice moving mantra to look at while switching the brain off :))

In hard drives with multiple platters, each side of each disk had its own read head, and all of them could be doing I/O simultaneously.

No. This sounds like mixing drums with disks. And even with drums, there was usually only one signal path connected to en/decoding. After all, multiplying en/decoder would drive the price up without bringing any real world advantage - at least not with the data rates systems could handle.
Devices with multiple simultaneous working heads were extreme rare special designs for high speed data acquisition. Usually build from the same drive mechanics, but with additional electronics and close connected to whatever data source. And since this was all about speed, drums where the usual base, as zero head movement beats even the fastest one :)) Reading in turn was usually one head at a time, so the computer could cope with the speed.

Data was written cylinder-first bits written simultaneously in parallel), and then the track was written (one rotation), and only then would the head move.

Make that serial and it works. Tracks weer written in sequence of heads, then the head moved and so on. So continuous writing on a 14 head disk would move the head every 14th track.

I'm not familiar with any PC defragmenting software that paid attention to cylinders. Or maybe they all did, and they just never talked about it.

Well, one should never say never, but it would be quite a surprise. Sure, it could have been done, as long as the software would know about the disk geometry. Like with the original PC-XT 10 MB drive. Its CHS values were

306 Cylinders,
4 Heads and
17 Sectors per track.

This drive also fits nicely within the BIOS API limit of 1024 cylinders, 255 heads and 63 sectors/track. So reading those values was possible and likewise acting upon. It got of course more limited when disks grew, as thay didn't grew nicely where room is - like having more heads - but almost exclusive along the number of cylinders by packaging them ever more (*1)
As soon as drives went past 1024 cylinders - which happened somewhere around 30-60 MB - CHS values used at the BIOS interface were no longer reflecting the real disk structure. 'Virtual' heads were invented the same way as virtual sectors - that is a track was reported as having anything up to 63 sectors instead of it's real value.
As a result CHS numbers had no relation to the real disk structure. Thus any program trying to use those to gain further optimization may as well not optimize at all.
Not sure about when you started, but I would assume way past the point when Disks had only 10 or 20 MiB :))

Now, for the original idea, it would of course be a helpful idea to aligning files at cylinder boundaries (*2) - an that's what has been done back in the age of early mainframes. Early on, with CKD disks, 'file' assignment was done by cylinder anyway. That means the smallest unity a program could allocate was a cylinder.
But also later on, when CHS (like) schemes were used, programs had way more control over disk allocation and place files at cylinder borders. This worked especially well as most mainframe OS allow ahead of use allocation. Here any file usage is (may) be preceded by a file creation action which defines the parameters to be used, like

Which disk
Where to start
Initial size
Increments to be used when extending

This high degree of control(*3) no only guaranteed high speed, but also avoided much fragmentation in the first place.

Then there's another item where mainframe disks differed from micros: Multiple head coils. While there are as well modern drives with more than one head coil (*4), those could only transfer from one head from one of the coils at any time. Multiple head coils were only installed to cope with the ever increasing number of cylinders (*5). In contrast mainframe drives with two head coils could operate them complete Independent over all tracks, position and read/write simultaneous, allowing two fully parallel access operation at the same time. Of course such a drive was attached like two drives, occupying two drive addresses and so on.

*1 - Adding disks and heads is quite expensive as that's physical hardware. Putting more sectors means not only different material and more sensitive heads but especially higher frequencies and data rates, which need more expensive electronics. Adding more cylinders in turn 'only' needs finer head positioning, achievable at way lower cost.
2 - And yes, unlike one may assume at first, there is no wasting of space, as not all files need to be at the start of a cylinder. The point is just to have them if possible within a cylinder, so head movement can be avoided. So when taking the XT drive as example, a cylinder is 174=68 sectors or 34 ki-bytes. Thus if, lets say a 30 KiB file gets aligned to that cylinder, the remaining 4 KiB can be taken up by one or more smaller files. Same goes with files larger 34 KiB, except here it's the last cylinder used to be filled with small(er) files. Would work out quite nice, wouldn't it?
*3 - Note that these functionalities were highly OS and file system dependent, so not every OS provided all of that on every disk system.
*4 - Usually 'only' two. Not sure if there were any drived with more than two.
*5 - Head mounts of modern drives do not move linear, like in the olde days, but along an arc. With increasing angle (due to number of tracks) the head gets misaligned. To compensate, two head carriers were added, each covering only half of the tracks. Since both being able to operate independent, one could position while the other was reading/writing. A very welcome side effect.

The thing you mention - geometryʼs influence onto disk access timings - was worth a tiny attention, but it was not implemented in MS-DOS (in wide sense) file systems. For it you should look, for example, at UFS (Unix file system) development, mainly in BSD Unix and its followers. Drivers there used to get a gain from knowing the real geometry; parameters like sector interleave, rotational delay, etc. were detected during FS creation and written into disklabels and superblocks. Some fields are still present in active definitions (although have only historical sense).
At the early period of UFS filesystems, they were organized as a sequence of cylinder groups, each group containing superblock copy, cylinder group header, usage bitmaps, inode pool and file data pool. Their boundaries were exactly at cylinder boundaries. Books like "Design and implementation of 4.4BSD operating system" covered this in details. Later on, the boundary correlation vanished: what I observed at my FreeBSD/i386 installations was that a cylinder group might have been exactly 32MiB, 128Mib or so. But this was already in late 1990s - early 2000s or so, when disks started massively used zone based recording.
For defragmentation itself, I think this always had nearly zero sense. Defragmentation should maximally reduce an integral parameter like sum of all steps between consective block pairs. Reordering from block sequence like 1, 1001, 2, 1002, 3, 2003, 4, 5555, 5, 9876... - always gains great benefit. But if file blocks are like 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, even if there is the jump between cylinders at move from 35 to 36 - isn't worth attention, just IMHO. More so, since real geometry started being hidden from software view - starting with ZBR - any geometry reported by BIOS got really faked, and one couldnʼt rely on it. For all this, Iʼm certain the variant was considered multiple times and stably rejected each time.
(Notice also that idea of compressing a whole file into one contiguous block sequence was not always the only. UFS, which mentioned by me, utilized different strategies and one of them was to allocate no more than 1/2 of each cylinder group for a single file, adding artificial jumps between CGs for larger files - and this positively affected on integral file continuity even without an explicit defragmenter.)

If an application will be reading a file sequentially, then on a drive with S sectors per track, where I:1 sector interleave and inter-track skew are optimized for that task, reading all of the data for an N-block file stored as a sequential sequence of blocks will take roughly IN/S+0.5 rotations of the disk.  If there are small gaps in the sequence, skipping over sectors will take just as much time as reading them would have.  Note that if the sectors of a file were stored in reverse order, performance would be much slower than in forward order.

@supercat Right you are. This is why many formatting schemes included interleave inside a track. I remember one on Apple II (practically, Agat, but they were AFAIR equal here.) I donʼt know about interleave on HDDs of 1990-2000s, this is a separate question for this SE. But at this time disk caching with prefetching may override the issue.

From what I remember, defragmenters didn’t care about disk geometry, which makes sense. Disk geometry is low-level, specific to a given disk, and either hardcoded into the disk controller or handled by a low-level formatting utility, at least specific to a given manufacturer.
This process managed the angular skew between consecutive cylinders, the interleaving of sectors on the same cylinder, and even the skew across multiple platters/surfaces. The goal was to minimize latency between reading two consecutive (logical) sectors, accounting for the head movement speed, disk rotation speed, and data transfer time.
Defragmenters, by organizing data according to logical sectors, leveraged this complex physical structure to speed up sequential reading of large volumes. However, they did not change the access time to individual files, as head movement was still required in any case.
Nowadays, controllers are fast enough to eliminate the need for sector interleaving, the LBA mode has rendered knowledge of the actual disk geometry almost obsolete, low-level formatting is performed in the factory and is no longer accessible to end users, and the presence of significant cache memory has effectively sealed the coffin for "optimized" physical disk geometry. And, of course, none of this has any relevance for SSDs.

It would be pointless. The real trouble was that the File Allocation Table itself is stored as a linked list in the FAT file system, leading to the issue that in the event of file fragmentation, there would be many seeks of the FAT table itself, that had to be done in order, and the OS of the time were too memory constrained / too stupid to cache it.
Once the FAT entries for the file had been read, the data could in principle be read in any order. By defragmenting the disk, the FAT entries were then next to each other so would hopefully be read within a couple of reads. All of this is within the first few cylinders, and the end of the disk where the backup table is

Why would the FAT be stored as a linked-list when it is created in toto at the time the file system is laid down on the empty disk?  I'm not saying you are wrong, but it seems like a strange choice. The allocation of a file is effectively a linked-list within the presumably-contiguous FAT.

Sorry, this is just wrong. The FAT was always cached. We have the source code for MSDOS 1.25, and in FATREAD, it literally says "If disk may have been changed, FAT is read in and buffers are flagged invalid. If not, no action is taken.". In other words, it's cached until the disk is changed.

Also, defragmentation is about moving the data sectors closer together, so they could be read continously, without having to move the head (which took time).

Defrag is for data. The FAT was allocated in a single extent, but if more space was needed, the FAT was extended into a second extent. Consolidating the FAT will only help once or twice, once for each time the FAT was extended.

@dirkt no one ever defragged floppy disks. and on a fat 12 system the number of fat entries is small enough this can be cached. By the time we get to FAT16 to go beyond 20MB disks, Id like to know how you think you are caching 2^16 entries 2 bytes per entry with 640K ram

@MissUnderstands the data location has to correspond to the entry in the fat table, which contains the links for where this next cluster is, if the file is more than 1 cluster. you can't move one without the other. unfortunately, with this filesystem design you don't know what clusters to access until you have read the linked list

@camelccc I already know how the file allocation table works. When I worked in a computer repair store, I once had to run down the FAT entries to assemble the extents and recreate someone's critical document. But that doesn't have anything to do with defragmenting the FAT.

I defragged UCSD Apple Pascal floppy disks quite often... but the point is that (1) caching was always there, to whatever extent, it wasn't "too stupid" as you claim (2) defragmentation has nothing to do with the FAT, it's all about making data files continuous to minimize head movements.

@dirkt this is frankly nonsense. Alternative filesystems of the time, UFS, ext etc , anything inode based was near immune to fragmentation (obviously not completely). as all the locations can be determined instantly, and the reads issued in an order that goes over the cylinders. FAT filesystems are exceedingly slow when fragmented because of the way the fat itself works. the thing has to be read in sequence unless you are going to keep the whole fat in memory. Trivial on a FAT12 system, impossible on a FAT16 system with 1 or 2 MB of memory.

@dirkt: Files on UCSD Pascal disks couldn't become fragmented; free space could, but that's a separate issue.  The sequential nature of UCSD files should have allowed Apple Pascal to achieve a level of performance close to the hardware's potential, but my recollection from back in the day was that everything seemed unduly slow.
